# Adding "defer" attribute to clientLib script tags in AEM 6.1

Tags: aem, htl

How would I add the defer attribute to our script tags? We get them via the clientLib tag call in our head.html but there's not much out there for AEM and how to easily add the defer tag to our scripts.

```html
<clientlib data-sly-call="${clientLib.all @ categories=['company-libraries']}" data-sly-unwrap/>
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use Jens answer: https://github.com/nateyolles/aem-clientlib-async but that one does not play nice with ACS commons versioned clientlib.which is why I made this: https://github.com/ahmed-musallam/aem-clientlib-async

Comment: Did not know about this one. Thank you for the link and your work :)

Comment: @Ahmed Musallam, can you please explain the issue which you had faced with Nate's version and ACS commons version client libs? Because I can see the hash in the final output. I had tried your version as well but that didn't work because in AEM 6.5 the generated link tag doesn't have an end tag, which makes it an invalid XML and due to that I am getting an exception.

Comment: @ankur_rajput as you can see,my answer is from June 2019. There might have been changes to ACS commons that broke my script. If you’d like to make a PR, go for it.

Comment: @AhmedMusallam, It's not an issue with ACS commons because it is not related to versioning. Instead in AEM 6.5 the link tag doesn't have any end tag (which is a valid HTML5), due to which the generated DOM doesn't fulfill the requirements of a valid XML and hence the parser is throwing an exception for link tag. I am in the testing phase of my solution. Once I get it worked, I'll definitely raise a PR.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this does not work out-of-the-box. But there is a project on GitHub exactly for this purpose (`async` and `defer` loading).

See: https://github.com/nateyolles/aem-clientlib-async

With that package you then can do:

```
<meta data-sly-call="${clientLib.js @ categories='your.clientlib', loading='defer'}" data-sly-unwrap></meta>
```

Comment: Nate’s does not play nice with ACS versioned clientlibs, that’s why I made a different impl: https://github.com/ahmed-musallam/aem-clientlib-async